# Python GUI and function calling using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to python and trying to build a GUI that takes from date and to date from user and reads the data accordingly from a csv file and display the urine output (calculated in the csvimport fucntion). I also want to plot the graph for a specific time and urine output in that time.

Can anyone help me? My code so far is below and it isn't displaying any GUI. Please can anyone correct the basic errors and help me in running this?

```
            import csv
            from tkinter import *
            from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
            from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning, showinfo
            import datetime




            #csv_file = csv.reader(open("C:\Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\DataLog.csv"))
            from Tools.scripts.treesync import raw_input
            class App(Frame):
                def __init__(self, master):
                    Frame.__init__(self, master)
                    self.in_file = None
                    button1 = Button(self, text="Browse for a file", command=self.askfilename)
                    button2 = Button(self, text="Count the file", command=self.takedate())
                    button3 = Button(self, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
                    button1.grid()
                    button2.grid()
                    button3.grid()
                    self.grid()

                def askfilename(self):
                    in_file = askopenfilename()
                    if not in_file.endswith(('.csv')):
                        showwarning('Are you trying to annoy me?', 'How about giving me a CSV file, genius?')
                    else:
                        self.in_file=in_file

                def CsvImport(csv_file):


                    dist = 0
                    for row in csv_file:
                        _dist = row[0]
                        try:
                            _dist = float(_dist)
                        except ValueError:
                            _dist = 0

                        dist += _dist
                    print ("Urine Volume is: %.2f" % (_dist*0.05))


                def takedate(self):
                    from_raw = raw_input('\nEnter FROM Date (e.g. 2013-11-29) :')
                    from_date = datetime.date(*map(int, from_raw.split('/')))
                    print ('From date: = ' + str(from_date))
                    to_raw = raw_input('\nEnter TO Date (e.g. 2013-11-30) :')
                    to_date = datetime.date(*map(int, to_raw.split('/')))
                    in_file = ("H:\DataLog.csv")
                    in_file= csv.reader(open(in_file,"r"))

                    for line in in_file:
                        _dist = line[0]
                        try:
                            file_date =  datetime.date(*map(int, line[1].split(' ')[1].split('/')))
                            if from_date <= file_date <= to_date:
                                self.CsvImport(in_file)

                        except IndexError:
                            pass






            root = Tk()
            root.title("Urine Measurement")
            root.geometry("500x500")
            app = App(root)
            root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *calling* `takedate` method as soon as you are initializing your class. Removing parentheses(which means, *call* the method) would solve your issue.

```
button2 = Button(self, text="Count the file", command=self.takedate())
                                                                   ^^ remove these
```

Your GUI doesn't show up because `takedate` method makes your program to wait for user input because of `raw_input(..)` calls.

You should consider using `Entry` instead of `raw_input()` for getting user input.

EDIT: You can put two Entry in your `__init__` then use Entry's get method in `takedate`. Roughly something like below.

```
def __init__(self, master):
    ...
    ...
    self.userInputFromRaw = Entry(self)
    self.userInputFromRaw.grid()

    self.userInputToRaw = Entry(self)
    self.userInputToRaw.grid()

def takedate(self):
    ...
    from_raw = self.userInputFromRaw.get()
    ...
    to_raw = self.userInputToRaw.get()
```

Also, you should add self parameter when defining your method since it is part of that class.

```
def CsvImport(self, csv_file):
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am confused as to where should i use **Entry**? in the **takedate** function? and how will I show that in the GUI if it is used in the **takedate** method?

Comment: hello. now when i enter the dates in the text field, the following error occurs: **TypeError: CsvImport() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given** can you help me more in this?

Comment: @rushan  When creating method, you should pass `self` as parameter since it's a part of your class. `def CsvImport(self, csv_file):`

Answer (score 1):

If you not want to pass parameters into `self.takedate()` remove `()`as below:

```
button2 = Button(self, text="Count the file", command=self.takedate)
```

or change to

```
button2 = Button(self, text="Count the file", command=lambda e=Null: self.takedate())
```

In this case you can pass `e` parameter to `self.takedate()`. Pass it to this maner:

```
command=lambda e=Null: self.takedate(e)
def takedate(self, parameter): pass
```